# Why is a question about dealing with ignored service requests off-topic?

Tags: discussion

[How To Handle An Ignored Request](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18152/how-to-handle-an-ignored-request)

This question the user is asking how to deal with that his technical service request is apparently being ignored.

To me this is plainly to do with negotiating the workplace, and I can't see why it would be offtopic.

Comment: I have no idea, but it now has a reopen vote. It may have to do with the flood of visitors we got yesterday putting a real damper on community moderation, or it could be something else. Hopefully the members who closed it can share their insight.

Comment: I agree with @jmac. That closure looks strange. I just added a reopen vote. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Post Reopened by jmac, Jim G., THE DOCTOR, gnat, enderland
>
> occurred Jan 18 at 15:50

Looks like the community ended up agreeing with you. It currently isn't closed, so the community doesn't think it's off-topic. Community moderation remains effective.

Comment: FWIW [first revision of the question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/revisions/18152/1) looked like hard to comprehend wall of text; it is quite likely that some of the voters thought it should be closed as unclear