# Why is this question considered off-topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question

One of our users, EMS, asked this question which has been put on hold by the community:

[Weighing pros and cons of quitting against other life circumstances](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18551/)

[He does not understand the reasoning behind it being closed](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18551/weighing-pros-and-cons-of-quitting-against-other-life-circumstances?noredirect=1#comment45863_18551) (the following has been abridged by me to get to the heart of his question from multiple comments, please read the full comment string to understand full context rather than assuming this is the discussion verbatim):

> Given that I have had a lot of experience with other Stack Exchange sites for the past few years, I always read a new site's guidelines and make an earnest effort to design questions that fit well within those guidelines. Our subjective opinions may differ about the question, but I have definitely tried to make it very clear what I am asking, and to ensure that what I am asking very clearly fits with the site's goals for productive questions.
>
> I've come to accept closed questions as part of the Stack Exchange world. Meta sites do not offer fair ways for question-posters to provide context and evidence that their questions, as-asked, do satisfy the FAQ and guidelines.
>
> Meta does not actually offer a fair chance for a user to defend their question as-asked. It's not difficult for four or five people to misinterpret a question, to subjectively dislike it, or to infer a tone that readers didn't generally infer. So the random opinion of four or five folks is not a good signal (although, sure, it's better than nothing). The trouble is that moderators who read meta essentially universally side with votes to close or migrate.
>
> meta discussions virtually never lead to a moderator saying, "You know what, the original post was valid as-it-was, so let's roll everything back to that and remove the close/migrate flags." This happens so rarely that it makes me lack faith in the process.
>
> I'd also like to point out that there are several answers to the question, some of which have several up-votes. They seem as on-topic for the site as any other post about quitting that I've read on this site. I believe this is further evidence that the votes to close, and the opinion that the question is "too vague", are unjustified. I don't expect anyone to agree with me, essentially because of the exact asymmetry problem I have been talking about (folks will just cheer for their side of the argument)

1. Is this question actually on-topic?
2. If not, why isn't it?

Comment: Any sense as to why EMS cares? He seems to have gotten as many answers/comments as could reasonably be expected. Why would he really care if the question is now closed?

Comment: @Joe, you could ask him. I don't really know. [His history of programmers meta may give some hints](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/users/103181/ems).

Answer (score 4):

1. SE is not about you (or me, or him, or her)
2. Give respect to gain respect
3. Voice your concerns appropriately

### SE is not about you

> Our subjective opinions may differ about the question, but I have definitely tried to make it very clear what I am asking, and to ensure that what I am asking very clearly fits with the site's goals for productive questions.

This isn't about how hard you tried, or how much you think your question is appropriate for the site. The goal of SE is to be a long-term resource for people facing similar problems. If the community does not agree that your question will meet those goals, we may [edit it aggressively](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2153/aggressive-edits), vote to close it, or handle it as we see fit.

That is a fundamental tenet. And it applies to everything I contribute just as equally as it does to what you contribute. If it doesn't have lasting value, we don't want it here. What constitutes lasting value is subjective, and comes down to [I know it when I see it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_know_it_when_I_see_it) a lot of the time. No amount of debating over the letter of the law will change the reason those rules exist: to make a better resource.

### Give Respect to Gain Respect

> It's not difficult for four or five people to misinterpret a question, to subjectively dislike it, or to infer a tone that readers didn't generally infer. So the random opinion of four or five folks is not a good signal

There are [261 members with 500 reputation](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/195/alltime/workplace/2012-04-10?sort=reputationchange&page=6) (who have the [ability to close and reopen questions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions)). We are not 'random people', we are members of this community who have put time in to understand what our community standards are, and what types of questions will make us a better resource.

The 5 people who closed your question are #6, #14, #30, #9, and #66 for reputation in our community. We all have experience with both the meta discussions on what constitutes quality questions on this site, as well as read countless questions (and provided many answers) to people who ask questions here. We are pretty far from 'random people' when it comes to maintaining the quality of content on this site.

We are not out to get you. SE is not about you. It's about quality content.

### Voice your concerns

> Meta does not actually offer a fair chance for a user to defend their question as-asked.

It is fine to disagree with us. You too are part of the community. But there is a time and a place for it. Making passive-aggressive comments to people trying to help is not appropriate. Remember to [be nice](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).

We are all human. We all make mistakes. Our word is not gospel. But if you want to bring up a disagreement, do it in the proper venue (meta). Here we are more than happy to hear what you have to say about your question and why you think it should be handled differently. [And it does work sometimes](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2274/why-is-a-question-about-dealing-with-ignored-service-requests-off-topic).

There are 256 people who have the power to reopen your question. If, at the end of the day we disagree, then you can be a good sport and make an appropriate edit to your question, or take our comments to heart for the next time that you ask a question. We are all reasonable people and willing to listen, all we ask is that you do the same in return.

Comment: Pretty much sums it up....and then some!

Comment: I appreciate reading these perspectives. I hope all of you also understand that when someone asks questions regarding the workplace, the workplace is the status quo, when someone complains against the status quo, others may resent it and backlash may be the result, such as voting to hold and close a post. I am not saying that this is what has happened, not even in my recently held post, but it is a reality. Just because we are on this wonderful platform does not mean that people check their fears and prejudices at the door. That would be the hope, but don't expect it.